# piping df into geom_hline parameters

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Trying to understand why the following works

```
stackover_df %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x=sample_name, y=estimate, group=sample_name, color=sample_name))+ 
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = stackover_df %>% filter(sample_name == "control1") %>% pull(upper_limit_value)))
```

but if I simply change the stackover_df to . for the geom_hline part

```
stackover_df %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x=sample_name, y=estimate, group=sample_name, color=sample_name))+ 
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = . %>% filter(sample_name == "control1") %>% pull(upper_limit_value)))
```

I get the following error message

> Error: Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): yintercept = . %>% filter(sample_name == "control1") %>% pull(upper_limit_value).
> Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add after_stat()?

Thanks!

Here's the sample data

```
stackover_df <- structure(list(sample_name = c("control1", "control2", "S01", 
"S02", "S03", "S04", "S05", "S06", "S07", "S08"), estimate = c(1.703, 
5.553, 4.851, 5.257, 4.573, 3.278, 1.687, 3.628, 1.877, 5.826
), std.error = c(1.767, 2.382, 1.641, 1.062, 1.133, 1.477, 0.978, 
0.611, 1.893, 0.78), upper_limit_value = c(5.166, 10.223, 8.067, 
7.339, 6.795, 6.173, 3.605, 4.825, 5.586, 7.355), lower_limit_value = c(-1.761, 
0.884, 1.635, 3.175, 2.352, 0.384, -0.231, 2.431, -1.833, 4.298
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two things involved here.

1. Trying to reference the `yintercept` inside of `aes()` so it's looking for a column name in `data` to provide a per-row mapping to a value. This isn't what you want here, so first thing is remove the `aes()` and just reference it directly
2. Since `ggplot()` is really a series of function calls, you need to use an expression (defined by `{ ... }`) in order to group them and keep the incoming `.` accessible to all of the layers.

So that all looks like this:

```
stackover_df %>% 
  { # make it an expression
    ggplot(., aes(x=sample_name, y=estimate, group=sample_name, color=sample_name)) + 
      geom_point() +
      geom_hline(yintercept = filter(., sample_name == "control1") %>% pull(upper_limit_value))
    }
```

Comment: interesting approach. thanks! how would I be able to incorporate the aes component in this case then, e.g., changing linetype and color?

Comment: so you can change all of that stuff without `aes()`, just use it "naked", `geom_line(linetype = 3)`, and it will adjust the attributes of that layer